# position a div so it appears to be outside the mainwrapper (980px)

Tags: jquery, html, css, xhtml

I want to position a div so it appears to be outside the mainwrapper (980px) of the site. the problem is i don't want there to be horizontal scrollbars in 1024px.

css or jquery solution would be great

any ideas?

the outside bit should be on the right, not the left

Answer (score 1):

Give the main-wrapper a position of `relative`, and the child element a position of `absolute`. You can then position the child with `left` and `top`.

```
<style>
  body { overflow-x:hidden }
  #wrapper { position:relative }
  #floating-sidebar { position:absolute; top:0; left:-100px; width:100px }
</style>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="floating-sidebar">
    <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any jQuery solution would just act as a middle-man for the aforementioned method, or one similar.

Answer (score 0):

css:

```
overflow-x: hidden;
```

Is a brute force way of sorting it

Answer (score 0):

use absolute positioning

Here is an example:

```
<style>
    #outsideDiv { position:absolute; left:90%; top:0; }
</style>

<div id="container">
    <div id="innerContainer">
        <p>his is some sample text</p>
    </div>
    <div id="outsideDiv">
        <p>This is the text displayed outside the div container</p>
    </div>
</div>
```